# polymer 404 on actualise (F5) on server only (working on local)

Tags: polymer, http-status-code-404, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I'm new to polymer. I followed the starter kit and created some pages. On my PC localhost, everything works fine. But once deployed to the server, I've got the following problem :
- I can access the site
- I can navigate between my different pages
- but if I try to access directly to a page or if I actualize my browser page when navigating : I get a 404
I don't underdstand why.
Do you have any idea ?

my case : www.tora-photo.com -> works
http://tora-photo.com/gallery/mist -> 404 but can be accessed from the previous url

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

the solution : use use-hash-as-path in app-location and add hash to href source

Comment: By saying add hash to href source do you mean

`<a href="#/link">Link</a>`

or

`<a href="/link" hash></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs to redirect all paths to your index.html which is actually handling your routing. The server is returning a 404 because you don't hactually have a file file called index.html in the /gallery/mist/ folder from the root of your web servers base.